# Selecting the one maximum row from each group

Tags: mysql, correlated-subquery

in example Xaprb
http://www.xaprb.com/blog/2006/12/07/how-to-select-the-firstleastmax-row-per-group-in-sql/
select maximum for each group

```
+--------+------------+-------+
| type   | variety    | price |
+--------+------------+-------+
| apple  | gala       |  2.79 | 
| apple  | fuji       |  0.24 | 
| apple  | limbertwig |  2.87 | 
| orange | valencia   |  3.59 | 
| orange | navel      |  9.36 | 
| pear   | bradford   |  6.05 | 
| pear   | bartlett   |  2.14 | 
| cherry | bing       |  2.55 | 
| cherry | chelan     |  6.33 | 
+--------+------------+-------+

select type, variety, price
from fruits
where price = (select min(price) from fruits as f where f.type = fruits.type);

+--------+----------+-------+
| type   | variety  | price |
+--------+----------+-------+
| apple  | fuji     |  0.24 | 
| orange | valencia |  3.59 | 
| pear   | bartlett |  2.14 | 
| cherry | bing     |  2.55 | 
+--------+----------+-------+
```

but if i have a fruits with some price the record are duplicated

```
+--------+----------+-------+
| type   | variety  | price |
+--------+----------+-------+
| apple  | fuji     |  0.24 | 
| apple  | fuji2    |  0.24 |
| orange | valencia |  3.59 | 
| pear   | bartlett |  2.14 | 
| cherry | bing     |  2.55 | 
+--------+----------+-------+
```

How can i get only one record per type in this case?

Answer (score 0):

Just group by `type`

```
select type, MIN(variety) AS variety, MIN(price) AS price
from fruits
where price = (select min(price) from fruits as f where f.type = fruits.type);
GROUP BY type
```

Whis this you get the first item (in alphabetical order)

BTW: you could also use `MAX`, just what you prefer

Comment: i can't use group, in select  i useing  column that don't participate in group and aggregate function

Comment: then give us your full `SELECT`statement

Comment: so there are `type`, `variety` and `price`? if so, why doesn't my statement work?

Answer (score 0):

Use a GROUP BY clause - i.e.

```
 select type, variety, price
 from fruits
 where price = (select min(price) from fruits as f where f.type = fruits.type)
 group by type;
```